# Tableau Creating a Timeline on only two dates

Tags: timeline, tableau-api

I'm working on a visualization of data which represents office markets.
Therefore I'm focussing on object level instead of regional, national or global market levels. Therefore I have to treat my data differently than what is regular.

Let me provide a simple dummy by text.

I have a building A {PropertyName} which has 3 tenants {CompanyName}, tenant A, B and C. Both tenant A and B have been in the building since it has been constructed {ConstructionDate}.

Tenant C has been in the building somewhat later (6 months later).

The building is built in 2011, and all tenants are still in the building. I want to calculate the following things. I know the building has a Size {PropertySize} of 5000 m2. The lease of tenant A is 2000 m2, tenant B also has 2000 m2 and tenant C has 1000 m2.

The problem I face at the moment is that I only have the initial starting date of the lease {StartDateLease} and if applicable, an end date of the lease {EndDateLease}.

I want to add Pages in Tableau which you can scroll through (by month or quarter) and that the leases are showed whenever they (the tenants) are in the building (i.e. leasing it) and whenever the end date of the lease has been reached (or if they are not yet in the building, as tenant C is) they are not present in the building and the {PropertySize} - SUM({LeaseSize}) is calculated {PropertyVacancy}.

Preferrable I would like to add this in a stacked bar chart as well to be showed. I hope this is clear for now.

**Summary of Data**

```
{PropertyName} {CompanyName} {StartDateLease} {EndDateLease} {LeaseSize} {PropertySize} {PropertyVacancy}
  Building A     Tenant A       01-01-2011       01-01-2016     2000         5000         [CalculatedValue]
```

And so on.

Could anybody help me out based on this maybe very vague explanation?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of business questions you could answer with your data, but I will try to stick to the question you asked. If you want to look at each quarter or month using Tableau's Page shelf, you're going to have to manipulate your data. You need a row for every Property, Tenant, and Month of the **calendar in which you are concerned**.  This means you'll be making lots more rows. Here's the beginning of what your data needs to look like for 1/1/2011 thru 4/1/2012:

```
    PropertyName    Occupied by Month   LeaseSpace
    Building A  Tenant A    1/1/2011    2000
    Building A  Tenant A    2/1/2011    2000
    Building A  Tenant A    3/1/2011    2000
    Building A  Tenant A    4/1/2011    2000
    Building A  Tenant A    5/1/2011    2000
    Building A  Tenant A    6/1/2011    2000
    Building A  Tenant A    7/1/2011    2000
    Building A  Tenant A    8/1/2011    2000
    Building A  Tenant A    9/1/2011    2000
    Building A  Tenant A    10/1/2011   2000
    Building A  Tenant A    11/1/2011   2000
    Building A  Tenant A    12/1/2011   2000
    Building A  Tenant A    1/1/2012    2000
    Building A  Tenant A    2/1/2012    2000
    Building A  Tenant A    3/1/2012    2000
    Building A  Tenant A    4/1/2012    2000
    Building A  Tenant B    1/1/2011    2000
    Building A  Tenant B    2/1/2011    2000
    Building A  Tenant B    3/1/2011    2000
    Building A  Tenant B    4/1/2011    2000
    Building A  Tenant B    5/1/2011    2000
    Building A  Tenant B    6/1/2011    2000
    Building A  Tenant B    7/1/2011    2000
    Building A  Tenant B    8/1/2011    2000
    Building A  Tenant B    9/1/2011    2000
    Building A  Tenant B    10/1/2011   2000
    Building A  Tenant B    11/1/2011   2000
    Building A  Tenant B    12/1/2011   2000
    Building A  Tenant B    1/1/2012    2000
    Building A  Tenant B    2/1/2012    2000
    Building A  Tenant B    3/1/2012    2000
    Building A  Tenant B    4/1/2012    2000
    Building A  NULL        1/1/2011    1000
    Building A  NULL        2/1/2011    1000
    Building A  NULL        3/1/2011    1000
    Building A  NULL        4/1/2011    1000
    Building A  NULL        5/1/2011    1000
    Building A  NULL        6/1/2011    1000
    Building A  Tenant C    7/1/2011    1000
    Building A  Tenant C    8/1/2011    1000
    Building A  Tenant C    9/1/2011    1000
    Building A  Tenant C    10/1/2011   1000
    Building A  Tenant C    11/1/2011   1000
    Building A  Tenant C    12/1/2011   1000
    Building A  Tenant C    1/1/2012    1000
    Building A  Tenant C    2/1/2012    1000
    Building A  Tenant C    3/1/2012    1000
    Building A  Tenant C    4/1/2012    1000
```

You will need to replace 'NULL' with either blank cells, "None", "No One", or whatever works for you. The reason you need this is so Tableau has a place to land when you scroll through each page of months or quarters.

This method also gives you the benefit of simply needing to `SUM(LeaseSpace)` at any point to get your `PropertySize` and if you drag your `[Occupied by]` dimension into the visualization, you'll have your `PropertyVacancy` for any given Month/Page.

Percent Occupied is a Calculated Field: `SUM(IF CONTAINS([Occupied by],'Tenant') THEN [LeaseSpace] END) / SUM([LeaseSpace])`

Let's say it's 2/1/2016 and you haven't renewed your leases with Tenants A and B.  Your records for that month would look like this:

```
    PropertyName    Occupied by Month   LeaseSpace
    Building A  Tenant C    2/1/2016    1000
    Building A  NULL        2/1/2016    4000
```

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate answer. I figured something out like this indeed but it is a very ineffecient way of having my raw data. I have added a "custom" time axis now who not really does the same but it shows the data where it needs to be. May I ask why you started off with the "there a lots of business questions you could answer with this data"?

Comment: You are correct in that it is an inefficient form of raw data.  I was showing what the data needs to look like to Tableau. You could keep your data stored efficiently and JOIN on a Calendar table if you have a database and add a Calendar table to that, but that's a different question/answer thread.

I started off the way I did because your data sparked a lot of ideas for meaningful visualizations in Tableau, but I wanted to at least mention that you had multiple opportunities while sticking to answering your actual question.

Comment: @coge.soft 
I believe I'm running into a similar issue where I'm trying to show a "line" for the duration of employment.  I have the start date month and year and the end date month and year.  Essentially, I just want my bar to span the length of my employment time. If I do the join using a calendar table wouldn't it only join on the start month and year and the end month and year?  Thanks.